# Calculating circle contact point and creating the 3-point arc in the vicinity of contact point

Tags: python-2.7, geometry, abaqus

Hii I am trying to calculate the contact point of two mating circles
    and for the calculated contact point I am trying to create 3 point arc 
    in the vicinity of the contact point (for both the operation I am 
    using contact point algorithm ). But the error in the second operation 
    as i am storing those array in a text file and again importing that 
    text file for the second operation. Is any better way to do that

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

```
    import numpy as np  
    from math import sqrt
    import math as math 
    fd =open('circle_input.txt','r')
    d=np.loadtxt(fd,delimiter=',',dtype={'names':('co1','col2','col3'),'formats':('float','float','float')})
    fd_1 =open('circle_input.txt','r')
    fd_2= open('circle_input.txt','r')
    d_1=np.loadtxt(fd_1,delimiter=',',dtype={'names':('co1','col2','col3'),'formats':('float','float','float')})
    d_2=np.loadtxt(fd_2,delimiter=',',dtype={'names':('co1','col2','col3'),'formats':('float','float','float')})
    temp1=d_1
    temp2=d_2

    for j in range (0,len(d)):

            if j==0:
                temp1[0]=temp1[j]
                temp1[j]=temp2[0]
                print(temp1)
            else:
                temp1[0]=temp1[j]
                temp1[j]=temp2[j-1]
                print(temp1)
                #print('\n')
            theta=0
            x0=d[j][0]+((d[j][2])*math.cos(theta))
            y0=d[j][1]+((d[j][2])*math.sin(theta))
            with open('output.txt','w') as f:
                for q in range(j+1,len(d)):
            if j!=q:
                x0,y0,r0,x1,y1,r1=d[j][0],d[j][1],d[j][2],d[q][0],d[q][1],d[q][2]
                dis=sqrt((x1-x0)**2+(y1-y0)**2)
                if dis<=(r0+r1):
                    a=(r0**2-r1**2+dis**2)/(2*dis)
                    h=sqrt(r0**2-a**2)
                    x2=x0+(a*(x1-x0)/dis)
                    y2=y0+(a*(y1-y0)/dis)
                    if dis==(r0+r1):
                        yc=y2-(h*(x1-x0)/dis)
                        xc=x2+(h*(y1-y0)/dis)
                        rc=((r0+r1)/4) # IMP Trick (#)
                        f.writelines(str(xc)+','+str(yc)+','+str(rc)+'\n') # important
                        f.writelines(str(d[j][0])+','+str(d[j][1])+','+str(d[j][2])+'\n')

                    else:# This part is passive
                        xc1=x2+(h*(y1-y0)/dis)
                        yc1=y2-(h*(x1-x0)/dis)
                        xc2=x2-(h*(y1-y0)/dis)
                        yc2=y2+(h*(x1-x0)/dis)
                                    print(str(xc)+','+str(yc)+','+str(rc)+'\n')
                                    print(str(d[j][0])+','+str(d[j][1])+','+str(d[j][2])+'\n')


            fd1 =open('output.txt','r')
            d1=np.loadtxt(fd1,delimiter=',',dtype={'names':('co1','col2','col3'),'formats':('float','float','float')})
              #command for upgrading thr oupput_contact.txt
            with open("output.txt") as f:
                with open("output_full.txt", "w") as f1:
                for line in f:
                    f1.write(line)
            open('output.txt', 'w')
            #
            with open('output_contact.txt','w') as f1:
                x0=np.zeros(len(d1))
                y0=np.zeros(len(d1)) 
                r0=np.zeros(len(d1)) 
                x1=np.zeros(len(d1))
                y1=np.zeros(len(d1)) 
                r1=np.zeros(len(d1)) 
                for p in range(0,len(d1)/2):
                    p=p+p
                    for q in range(p+1,p+2):
                    if p!=q:
                                     x0,y0,r0,x1,y1,r1=d1[p][0],d1[p][1],d1[p][2],d1[q][0],d1[q][1],d1[q][2]
                                     dis=sqrt((x1-x0)**2+(y1-y0)**2)                        
                                     if dis==(r0+r1):
                                         a=(r0**2-r1**2+dis**2)/(2*dis)
                                         h=sqrt(r0**2-a**2)
                                         x2=x0+(a*(x1-x0)/dis)
                                         y2=y0+(a*(y1-y0)/dis)
                                         if dis < (r0+r1):
                                             xc1=x2+(h*(y1-y0)/dis)
                                             yc1=y2-(h*(x1-x0)/dis)
                                             xc2=x2-(h*(y1-y0)/dis)
                                             yc2=y2+(h*(x1-x0)/dis)
                                             xc3=((x0+x1)/2)
                                             yc3=((y0+y1)/2)
                #f1.writelines(str(xc1)+','+str(yc1)+'\n'+str(xc2)+','+str(yc2)+'\n')
                print(str(xc1)+','+str(yc1)+','+str(xc2)+','+str(yc2)+','+str(xc3)+','+str(yc3)+'\n')




# circle_input.txt 
0,0,5
10,0,5
0,10,5
```

Comment: Why not use calculated variables?

Comment: Yes ..but I do want them in text file to do analysis further

Comment: And what is an error?

Comment: How many decimal digits do you store? Contact (tangent) point and vecinities are prone to numerical precision issues.